# как мне перехватить этот вид исключения

Tags: php, laravel

Как в  laravel сделать если не авторизован пользователь и вызвать Auth::user()->id; то возвращается ошибка Trying to get property of non-object как ее заменить на свое сообщение и редирект ? catch не отлавливаеться.

```
try{

         $comment= new CommentNews();
         $comment->text=$request->text;
         $comment->user_id=Auth::user()->id;
         $comment->public_id=$request->$p_id;
         $comment->save();

          return response()->json(['success'=>'Наш волонтер свяжется с Вами в ближайшее время! Благодарим за проявленный интерес']);


          }   
     catch (Exception  $exception) {
           echo('error');die;
           }
              }
             else{
                return response()->json(['errors'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);
            }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4):

1) Проверку на авторизацию лучше делать через мидлвары. Готовый в Ларавел уже есть auth.

2) Если делать в лоб, то сначала проверяете наличие юзера, а потом уже достаете id.

```
if(!Auth::user()) throw new Exception("your message");
$comment->user_id=Auth::user()->id;
```

Но это плохой вариант, лучше через первый. Документация: https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication

3) И да, это было не исключение, а ошибка, поэтому и не перехватывалось.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю использовать middleware auth на ваш route.

Красиво, локанично и всем понятно.

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        // Uses first & second Middleware
    });
});
```

Ещё один вариант использования.

```
Route::get('admin', function () {
    //
})->middleware('admin');
```

```
Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@show')->middleware('admin');
```

Ссылка на документацию [тык.](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware)